# How do I change the text of the "open" button in UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I've got an iOS app using the document picker view. [Image demonstrating the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOZPR.png)

When testing it however, I get the text "done" instead of what ideally would be "open" in the file picker when the user is prompted to proceed with the selection. How can I change the text of this button?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say, but my first thought would be to use a ternary operator to flip the title of your Done/Open button. Can you post the code where you are using the button in question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.